# Copying mssql DB to laravel sail docker container

Tags: sql-server, docker, ssms

I'm trying to use SqlServer as my DB repo in a laravel project running in [sail](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail).

Here's the relevant lines from the laravel `docker-compose.yml`

```
mssql:
    image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest'
    ports:
        - '${MSSQL_FORWARD_DB_PORT:-1432}:1433' // running on nonstandard port because I have other containers running
    environment:
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
        MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "MyDBP@ssword!1"
    networks:
        - sail
    volumes:
        - 'sail-mssql:/data/mssql'
```

I can connect to the Docker SqlServer instance from SSMS using my expected connection of `tcp:localhost,1432` but when I try to run the "copy" operation from a local DB to the remote container, it gives the following error:

```
TITLE: Copy Database Wizard
------------------------------

The action you attempted to perform on a remote SQL Server instance failed because the 
action requires a SQL Server component that is not installed on the remote computer. To    
proceed, install Microsoft SQL Server Management Tools on the remote computer, and then 
try again. For more information, see "How to: Install Microsoft SQL Server (Setup)" in 
Microsoft SQL Server Books Online, or find the article on MSDN at  
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=57083 .

For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=57083

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Naturally, the URL returns a 404 on the MS docs site, and every MSDN article I can find simply tells me to install `SQL Server command-line tools` instead `Microsoft SQL Server Management Tools`. This doesn't help unfortunately-- the command line tools are already installed with the docker image.

Is it possible to copy a DB from a Windows machine to Docker via SSMS

Comment: _from a local DB to the remote container_ ... so are they on the same computer (the Docker host)? If you're trying to copy between seperate computers then computer Source cannot connect to computer Dest's `localhost` ports because those are only accessible to Dest itself. In that scenario you might choose to use `- '${MSSQL_FORWARD_DB_PORT:-0.0.0.0:1432}:1433'` instead.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning sorry, the terminology can be confusing (to me). The docker container and my local DB are both on the same machine. I am maybe improperly thinking of the docker DB instance as "remote" since it's sort of a vm.

Comment: Have you tried enabling native backup/restore options? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.SQLServer.Options.BackupRestore.html

Comment: "when I try to run the "copy" operation" ... *how* you're doing that would probably be relevant information. As well as the versions of SQL Server on both your computer and the docker container. Database administration is not programming, so this maybe not be the best place to be asking the question.